# Google Maps V3 seems to ignore version parameter

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openlayers

In my OpenLayers app I want to embed version 3.6 of the google maps api and thus request it like so:

`<script type="text/javascript" scr="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&sensor=false"></script>`

unfortunately google maps seems to send version 3.7 instead, at least the response contains:

`getScript("http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/de_de/mapfiles/api-3/7/17/main.js");`

this breaks my OpenLayers Map, because with every map move a copyright popup is displayed, although the map already shows the proper attribution credits. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been discussed on the OpenLayers github page [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/commit/b17c7b69f25ce0ddbaf720f91b7d48328b005831#commitcomment-1343896). there are several options for solving the problem discussed. The quickest hacky fix is to add the following css,

```
.olLayerGooglePoweredBy {
     visibility:hidden;
}
```

This does potentially break the terms of use, so i cant fully recommend it. It would be more wise to apply the patch discussed on the ticket. Also asking on there will probably get you a good answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Version 3.6 has been withdrawn.

http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/msg/3f73f6593a787b7f

There's also http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify which it's a good idea to subscribe to.

Bugs should be reported in the issues tracker: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list (I can't find a relevant report for this issue). You will need to include a link to a demonstrator.